# Can I increase my review reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, review, review-audits, review-suspension

Is there any action we can do to increase our reputation in review?

For example, imagine I was banned from the review queues for 30 days. After this period, is there something I can do that will end the review ban earlier?

If (after being allowed to review again) I make some incorrect reviews will I get just 7 days or 30 days of ban instead of 90 days or a year-long ban?

One more question, is the general reputation affected by the review ban?

Comment: The SE network has only one concept of reputation, and that's the rep number by your name. Other than granting access to review queues, that number does not interact with reviewing much at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no method to get out of a review ban early.

Take into account that a review ban is there to protect the system from reviewers who have not passed fail-safe checks in the review process.  You failed several audits and were first banned for shorter periods.

Gaining reputation has no bearing on your ability to review. Posting a good answer or question does not tell us that you now know how to review properly.

Perhaps you can read up on your site's Meta to see how others review posts and have handled audits in the past. Once your 30-day review ban is over, the system is reset, and you are given a new chance to prove yourself. Review carefully!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's any way to end a review ban early -- just wait it out.

General reputation is independent of access to the review queues.

Comment: What do you mean by reputation though? Are you referring to points, or reputation in the queues?